# Use parent model data in other model through contains() and conditions, in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a contain statement that looks like this:

```
    $this->Wijken->contain(array(
        'Theme' => array(
            'Polygon' => array(
                'PolygonPoint'
            )
        )
    ));
```

The Polygon table has (among others) the fields 'theme_id' and 'wijk_id' (which is the primary key of Wijken).

What I want is to only fetch the Polygons that match with wijk_id.

So in my head, this would be achieved by adding the following to the Polygon-array:

```
'conditions' => array('wijk_id' => $this->Wijken.id)
```

However, this doesn't work. When I hardcode the value to 1, it works and I only get the polygons for wijk #1.

So my question is; How can you use the parent's model (Wijken) variable in another model's conditions variable (Polygon).
Or should I add special rules to my models?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the contain settings when you make a call to find() instead.  This will allow you to dynamically pass the Wijken id. ie:

```
function view($id) {
    // assuming $id param is a wijken id
    $contain = array(
        'Theme' => array(
            'Polygon' => array(
                'conditions' => array('Polygon.wijk_id' => $id),
                'PolygonPoint'
            )
        )
    );
    $conditions = array('Wijken.id' => $id);
    $wijken = $this->Wijken->find('first', array('contain'=>$contain, 'conditions'=>$conditions));
}
```

Comment: Wijken.id doesn't have to be filtered. What I want is all Wijken, with corresponder themes and polygons.. where the polygons need the wijken.id (wijk_id in their table) condition.

Comment: That's what the code above will get you.  Just do a find('all', array('contain'=>$contain)